# CSS If div's height is greater than 100vh, then add margin-bottom to div

Tags: html, css

I want to add `margin-bottom: 40px;` to a div if the height of the div is greater than the maximum view height (100vh). Is it possible to do this with css?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.foot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  I want user to be able to scroll and view all p elements in the body, however they should not overlap the footer. So I want to give bottom margin to the body class if it's height is greater than 100vh.

  <div class="body">
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
    <p>The number of this element is variable</p>
  </div>

  <div class="foot">
    <p>THIS SHOULD ALWAYS BE DISPLAYED AT THE BOTTOM</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think this is only possible with javascript. For what is the 40px needed? Can't you just make the diff always 40px away from the bottom with height: calc(100vh - 40px)

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: @OliverStahl check now. I have added code snippet of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

If the child div has position: "absolute", it can work, but if the div is a child div without position: "absolute", it is not possible. The maximum height for the div child is the same height as the div father.

idk, if you can understand:

```
<div style={s.father}>
   <div style={s.child}>
     <p>Hello</p>
   </div>
</div>
```